# Canvas animate images rotation

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, rotation

I want to create a background for my script on a canvas that makes images fall and rotate down the screen. So would someone be able to explain to me how I would rotate an image and then draw it to the screen using the `<canvas>` element. I have the following code:

```
    Equations.prototype.Draw = function() {
        //increases the rotational value every loop
        this.rotate = (this.rotate + 1) % 360;
        //rotates the canvas
        ctx.rotate(this.rotate*Math.PI/180);
        //draw the image using current canvas rotation
        ctx.drawImage(this.img,this.x,this.y);
        //restore canvas to its previous state
        ctx.rotate(-this.rotate*Math.PI/180);
    };
```

I try this and find that the image rotates but also moves around the screen as well in a circular shape around point (0,0) i want it to stay in the same place rotating on the spot. How would i fix this thanks!

Comment: [canvas transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations)

Comment: Please don't ask for "please write me a tutorial". Do some research, post some code and point to a specific issue! See [ask] and do please create a [mcve]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I could have put my code in the question saying i have this code that moves items down the screen but how do i then also rotate them as they move but then i get a peice of revised code back which doesnt give me understanding. I have done research and found rotation,translation and many more but they are not very well explained. Hence i am asking here. all i was asking was how to rotate an image in javascript a very s imple question probably worthy of 10 lines or less of an answer and would give me good understanding as well and 10 lines doesnt seem like a lengthly tutorial to me

Comment: @SamuelNewport. Welcome to Stackoverflow! The format of Stackoverflow is for you to give us what you have coded so far and then ask for help on that code. So yes, you should give us a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable version of you code when asking for help rather than just asking for help. ;-)

Comment: okay xD sorry i didnt realise @markE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the `context`, transform it, rotate it, paint, restore it.

```js
const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m,
  PI = Math.PI,
  TAU = PI * 2,
  width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight,
  ctx = document.getElementById('cvs').getContext('2d'),
  items = [],
  Item = function() {
    this.h = 32;
    this.w = 32;
    this.IMG = new Image();
    this.IMG.src = 'http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
    this.start();
    return this;
  };
  
Item.prototype.start = function() {
  this.x = rand(0, width - this.w / 2);
  this.y = rand(0, height);
  this.angle = rand(0, TAU);
  this.speed = rand(0.1, 0.5);
}

Item.prototype.move = function() {
  // Manipulate properties
  if (this.y > height + this.h) { // if is below bottom
    this.start();
    this.y = -this.h; // restart from top
  }
  this.y += this.speed / 0.1;
  this.angle += this.speed;
  this.angle %= TAU;

  // Manipulate context 
  ctx.save(); // save context
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y); // move to point
  ctx.rotate(this.angle); // rotate around that point
  ctx.drawImage(this.IMG, -this.w/2, -this.h/2);
  ctx.restore(); // restore to initial coordinates 
};

// Setup canvas
ctx.canvas.width = width;
ctx.canvas.height = height;

// Create falling Icons
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) items.push(new Item());

// Animation loop
(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  items.forEach(Item => Item.move());
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}());
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
canvas {display: block;}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains why my rotation was rotating about point (0,0) rather than the x and y co-ordinates Thanks!