# HTML5 Canvas animate the rotation of image around Y axis

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I have an image on a canvas:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 350);
  }
  img.src = "/img.png";
```

Can an image be rotated around the Y axis? The 2d Canvas API only seems to have a `rotate` function that rotates around the Z-axis.

Comment: Hmm you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422251/canvas-animate-images-rotation

Comment: I saw it however it rotates around forward axis(perpendicular to the screen) I need to rotate around up axis(parallel to vertical side of the screen)

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate around whatever axis you want. Using the save-transform-restore method covered in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422251/canvas-animate-images-rotation), we can do something similar by transforming a DOMMatrix object and applying it to the canvas.

Sample:

```js
// Untransformed draw position
const position = {x: 0, y: 0};
// In degrees
const rotation = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0};
// Rotation relative to here (this is the center of the image)
const rotPt = { x: img.width / 2, y: img.height / 2 };

ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(new DOMMatrix()
    .translateSelf(position.x + rotPt.x, position.y + rotPt.y)
    .rotateSelf(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z)
);
ctx.drawImage(img, -rotPt.x, -rotPt.y);
ctx.restore();
```

This isn't a "true" 3d, of course (the rendering context is "2d" after all). I.e. It's not a texture applied to some polygons. All it's doing is rotating and scaling the image to give the illusion. If you want that kind of functionality, you'll want to look at a WebGL library.

---

Demo:

- I drew a cyan rectangle around the image to show the untransformed position.
- Image source from MDN (see snippet for url).

```js
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage/canvas_drawimage.jpg";

let rotCounter = 0;
let motionCounter = 0;

function draw() {
  // Untransformed draw position
  const position = {
    x: motionCounter % canvas.width,
    y: motionCounter % canvas.height
  };
  // In degrees
  const rotation = {
    x: rotCounter * 1.2,
    y: rotCounter,
    z: 0
  };
  // Rotation relative to here
  const rotPt = {
    x: img.width / 2,
    y: img.height / 2
  };

  ctx.save();
  ctx.setTransform(new DOMMatrix()
    .translateSelf(position.x + rotPt.x, position.y + rotPt.y)
    .rotateSelf(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z)
  );
  // Rotate relative to this point
  ctx.drawImage(img, -rotPt.x, -rotPt.y);
  ctx.restore();

  // Position
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'cyan';
  ctx.strokeRect(position.x, position.y, img.width, img.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

  rotCounter++;
  motionCounter++;
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=600 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Rotate without perceptive

If you only want to rotate around the y Axis without perspective then you can easily do it on the 2D canvas as follows.

Assuming you have loaded the image the following will rotate around the image Y axis and have the y axis align to an arbitrary line.

The arguments for `rotateImg(img, axisX, axisY, rotate, centerX, centerY)`

- `img` a valid image.
- `axisX`, `axisY` vector that is the direction of the y axis. To match image set to - `axisX = 0`, `axisY = 1`
- `rotate` amount to rotate around image y axis in radians. 0 has image facing screen.
- `centerX` & `centerY` where to place the center of the image

```
function rotateImg(img, axisX, axisY, rotate, centerX, centerY) {
    const iw = img.naturalWidth;
    const ih = img.naturalHeight;

    // Normalize axis
    const axisLen = Math.hypot(axisX, axisY);
    const nAx = axisX / axisLen;
    const nAy = axisY / axisLen;

    // Get scale along image x to match rotation
    const wScale = Math.cos(rotate);

    // Set transform to draw content
    ctx.setTransform(nAy * wScale, -nAx * wScale, nAx, nAy, centerX, centerY);

    // Draw image normally relative to center. In this case half width and height up
    // to the left. 
    ctx.drawImage(img, -iw * 0.5, -ih * 0.5, iw, ih);

    // to reset transform use
    // ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

### Demo

The demo uses a slightly modified version of the above function. If given an optional  color as the last argument. It will shade the front face using the color and render the back face as un-shaded with that color.

The demo rotates the image and slowly rotates the direction of the image y axis.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height;
const img = new Image;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=256&g=1";
img.addEventListener("load", () => requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop), {once:true});
function rotateImg(img, axisX, axisY, rotate, centerX, centerY, backCol) {
    const iw = img.naturalWidth;
    const ih = img.naturalHeight;
    const axisLen = Math.hypot(axisX, axisY);
    const nAx = axisX / axisLen;
    const nAy = axisY / axisLen;
    const wScale = Math.cos(rotate);
    ctx.setTransform(nAy * wScale, -nAx * wScale, nAx, nAy, centerX, centerY);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(img, -iw * 0.5, -ih * 0.5, iw, ih);
    if (backCol) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = wScale < 0 ? 1 : 1 - wScale;
        ctx.fillStyle = backCol;
        ctx.fillRect(-iw * 0.5, -ih * 0.5, iw, ih);
    }
}
function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    
    rotateImg(img, Math.cos(time / 4200), Math.sin(time / 4200), time / 500, W * 0.5, H * 0.5, "#268C");
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black; background: #147;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```